# How can an arbitrary grid of squares be drawn of various shapes and colored edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to see how to approach drawing a diagram like the following:

[image]

I would like to be able to specify the position of each visible square individually, rather than using a TikZ loop of some kind to define the positions. Perhaps a matrix is a good approach, but I'm not sure.

What would be a clear and flexible way to make a diagram like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loop you can do it like this. (But i think loops are great).

Create `grids` , `nodes` , ...

[image]

```
    \documentclass[tikz, border=30pt]{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \begin{document} \begin{tikzpicture}


\draw[thick] (0,0.5)--(-1,0.5) node[anchor=east] {Aaa};

\draw[thick] (0,1.5)--(-1,1.5) node[anchor=east] {Bbb};

\draw[thick] (0,2.5)--(-1,2.5) node[anchor=east] {Ccc};

\draw[thick] (0,3.5)--(-1,3.5) node[anchor=east] {Ddd};

\draw[thick] (0,4.5)--(-1,4.5) node[anchor=east] {Eee};



\node [draw=none,anchor=south,red] at (0.5,5) {name} ;
\node [draw=none,anchor=south,blue] at (2.5,5) {name} ;
\node [draw=none,anchor=south] at (4.5,5) {name} ;
\node [draw=none,anchor=south,green] at (6.5,5) {name} ;
\node [draw=none,anchor=south,gray] at (8.5,5) {name} ;

\draw[step=1cm] (0,0) grid (1,5); 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (0,0) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (0,1) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (0,2) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (0,3) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (0,4) {}; 


\draw[step=1cm,yellow] (2,0) grid (3,5); 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (2,0) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (2,1) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,xshift=0.5cm]90:{man}}] at (2,2) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (2,3) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (2,4) {}; 

\draw[step=1cm,green] (4,0) grid (5,5); 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (4,0) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (4,1) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (4,2) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (4,3) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (4,4) {}; 


\draw[step=1cm,blue] (6,0) grid (7,5); 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (6,0) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (6,1) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,xshift=0.5cm]90:{man}}] at (6,2) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (6,3) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (6,4) {};


\draw[step=1cm,red] (8,0) grid (9,5); 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (8,0) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (8,1) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,xshift=0.5cm]90:{man}}] at (8,2) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (8,3) {}; 
\node[label={[label distance=0cm,anchor=south,xshift=0.5cm]90:{text}}] at (8,4) {};

\end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```