# Word Vector with the help of Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, vector

I am trying to get an idea how to rebuilt the attached picture in tikz. Unfortunately, I am not really good in using Tikz at all, still I think its the best way to built it. Or is there an easier way to create such figure? Thanks for any advice.[image]

Comment: Most likely instead of only showing a mock up, you should try to produce the attached figure as best as you can do it, and post the code as your MWE.  That way I think you will get more answers, as it will show that you have put some thought into how to do it yourself, and let others know that you are not just looking for others to code it.

Comment: for start read *tikz & pgf manual*, also visit site http://www.texample.net/

Comment: Ti*k*Z seems overkill here. Why don't you just use a table? Why do you think you need Ti*k*Z? Ti*k*Z might be easiest, but not if you aren't very good with it and would have to learn how to do it!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can an arbitrary grid of squares be drawn of various shapes and colored edges?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356605/how-can-an-arbitrary-grid-of-squares-be-drawn-of-various-shapes-and-colored-edge)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 5mm,
  start chain = going below,
   box/.style = {draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=6mm,
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                 on chain}
                  ]
  \node (a) [box,pin=left:Royalty] {};                   
  \node[box,pin=left:Masculinity] {};
  \node[box,pin=left:Femininity] {};
  \node[box,pin=left:Age,
            label=below:$\vdots$] {};              
%
  \node (b) [box,right=of a,label=:King] {0.99};   
  \node[box] {0.99};
  \node[box] {0.05};
  \node[box,label=below:$\vdots$] {0.7};        
%
  \node (c) [box,right=of b,label=:???] {0.99};    
  \node[box] {0.99};
  \node[box] {0.93};
  \node[box,label=below:$\vdots$] {0.7};        
%
  \node (d) [box,right=of c,label=:Women] {0.99};  
  \node[box] {0.99};
  \node[box] {0.05};
  \node[box,label=below:$\vdots$] {0.7};        
%
  \node[box,right=of d,label=:Princess] {0.98};  
  \node[box] {0.02};
  \node[box] {0.94};
  \node[box,label=below:$\vdots$] {0.1};        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

you need to finish image yourself since i can't read your writing. and as said [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr), tikz probably is overkill for your image.

code is slightly advanced , so i encourage you to read *tikz & pgf manual*, at least part 3: TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm

**edit:** thanks to [Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/10995/henri-menke) your handwriting is deciphered and included in above image and code. the numbers are still not verified, this i left to you. (as exercises, where they are in code).

Answer (score 5):

I think it's a little easier with a matrix than Zarko's chain solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=1em,
  nodes={
    draw,
    anchor=south,
    minimum width=3em,
    minimum height=5ex
  }] (m) {
    & 0.99   & 0.99   & 0.02   & 0.98    \\
    & 0.99   & 0.05   & 0.01   & 0.02    \\
    & 0.05   & 0.93   & 0.999  & 0.94    \\
    & 0.7    & 0.6    & 0.5    & 0.1     \\
    & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={green!75!black,above=4ex,anchor=base}]
    \node at (m-1-2) {King};
    \node at (m-1-3) {Queen};
    \node at (m-1-4) {Woman};
    \node at (m-1-5) {Princess};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style=blue!75!white]
    \node[pin={left:Royalty}]     at (m-1-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Masculinity}] at (m-2-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Femininity}]  at (m-3-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Age}]         at (m-4-1.west) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We can also make a new node shape with does not have a border on the bottom which I call `house`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{house}
{
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle] % this is nearly a rectangle
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{mid east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{base east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle]{south east}
  \foregroundpath{
    % store lower right in xa/ya and upper right in xb/yb
    \southwest \pgf@xa=\pgf@x \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
    \northeast \pgf@xb=\pgf@x \pgf@yb=\pgf@y
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@ya}}
    \pgfsetarrowsstart{}
    \pgfsetarrowsend{}
 }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=1em,
  nodes={
    draw,
    house,
    anchor=south,
    minimum width=3em,
    minimum height=5ex
  }] (m) {
    & 0.99   & 0.99   & 0.02   & 0.98    \\
    & 0.99   & 0.05   & 0.01   & 0.02    \\
    & 0.05   & 0.93   & 0.999  & 0.94    \\
    & 0.7    & 0.6    & 0.5    & 0.1     \\
    & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\
  };
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style={green!75!black,above=4ex,anchor=base}]
    \node at (m-1-2) {King};
    \node at (m-1-3) {Queen};
    \node at (m-1-4) {Woman};
    \node at (m-1-5) {Princess};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[every node/.style=blue!75!white]
    \node[pin={left:Royalty}]     at (m-1-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Masculinity}] at (m-2-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Femininity}]  at (m-3-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={left:Age}]         at (m-4-1.west) {};
    \node[pin={[pin edge={draw=none}]left:$\cdots$}] at (m-5-1.west) {};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With regular `tabular` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{6ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l P{6ex}*{9}{c}@{}}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{}             &                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.18\hsize}X}{\color{green} King\hfill} &                       & \multicolumn{1}{>{\hsize=0.18\hsize}X}{\color{green} Queen}                       &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\color{green} Woman}                        &                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\color{green} Princess}                   \\[2ex] \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\color{blue}Royalty ---}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.99$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.99$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.02$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.98$} \T\\[3ex] \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\color{blue}Masculinity ---} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.99$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.05$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.01$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.02$} \T\\[3ex] \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\color{blue}Feminity ---}    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.05$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.93$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.999$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.94$} \T\\[3ex] \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{r|}{\color{blue}Age ---}         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.07$} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.6$}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.5$}   & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$0.1$} \T\\[3ex] \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4} \cline{6-6} \cline{8-8} \cline{10-10} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\color{blue}\cdots$}        &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\vdots$}   &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\vdots$}            &      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\vdots$}                    &      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\vdots$}                     &        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{$\vdots$} \T             
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As I can accept only 1 solution I've simply accepted the first one. Eventhough the table version is probably the most reasonable in this particular case.